# Join a RethinkDB Cluster using ReQL instead of command line argument

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm using Docker, and by default runs the RethinkDB process with only the `--bind all` argument.

To join the cluster requires the use of the `--join` argument, or a configuration file. To do this with Docker would now require a new Docker image to be made for this purpose.

How can I join a cluster using ReQL directly (thus eliminating the need to create a new Docker image). I could simply connect to the lone instance, add a row to a system table (like `server_status`), and the instance would connect to the newly entered external instance.

I could repeat this process for each node in the cluster. And makes things simpler for when nodes come up and go down, otherwise I would have to restart each RethinkDB process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker, we can override the `CMD` which invokes RethinkDB process with a custom command for customization the executing RethinkDB process. Instead of simply call `docker run rethinkdb`, we can pass an the rethinkdb command for joining to the first node.

Example using the [official RethinkDB docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/)

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9080:8080 rethinkdb
```

Then we can inspect its IP address, assume it's `172.17.0.2`, we can start second one:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 9081:8080 rethinkdb rethinkdb --join 172.17.0.2:29015 --bind all
```

Visit RethinkDB dashboard and you should see two nodes now.

Comment: Thanks I guess I was hoping to control this via ReQL so I could modify the server without taking it down and restarting it with new `--join` arguments when the cluster was changed.  This is a nice work around.